# Reordering divs as table cells

Tags: css

Lets say my layout is as follows:

## CSS:

```
#wrapper {display:table;}
#one, #two, #three {display: table-cell}
```

## HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

So by default, the output display is:

```
OneTwoThree
```

I'm trying to reorder it so `#one` and `#three` stay together in the same row, while `#two` drops below. After reading similar questions I thought the following would do the trick:

## CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #two {display:table-footer-group;}
}
```

However, this displays:

```
One
Three
Two
```

The result I'm after should be:

```
OneThree
Two
```

Can anyone please point out the problem with my approach and how best to resolve it?

Comment: What about changing `@media screen` to just  `@media`?

Comment: Have a look at flex display. With `display: flex` `flex-wrap: wrap` and `order` you might have the proper behavior https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You can have one or three on it's own row, but not the middle two, that breaks the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table-row` instead of `display: table-col`.
And I think flex based solution is better =)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
}
#one, 
#two, 
#three {
  display: table-row;
}
#two {
  display:table-footer-group;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one">One</div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
  <div id="three">Three</div>
</div>
```